# Update div's width dynamically using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, width

In a dice game I created a simple progress bar which supposed to dynamically show a player's progress. Here's the function:

```
function gameProgress(myScore) {
    let myProgress = document.getElementById('progress');
    let id = setInterval(frame, 50);

    function frame() {
            myProgress.style.width = myScore + 'px';
    }
}
```

The function accepts the game score and supposed to reflect it on the progress bar. What actually happens is that the div's style="width:" keeps on jumping back and forth showing 2px, 7px, 17px, 22px, 32px and so on.
Any way to solve this problem? I want the element to display the latest updated width only but not all the values.

Comment: Why are you running the frame method every 50ms? Wouldn't it be easier to update the progress bar whenever there actually is some progress? And where does the `prg` variable come from?

Comment: Also, the progress bar just becomes as wide as your score. I would expect it to be a percentage or something. Say the max score is 100, you would have to divide the score by 100 and multiply the max width of the progress bar with the calculated score percentage.

Comment: I wanted the progress bar to slowly move as the score changes. prg - My bad, updated the function variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you don't have to use setInterval if you are updating the width only at one time.

```
function gameProgress(myScore) {
    let myProgress = document.getElementById('progress');
    prg.style.width = myScore + 'px'; // this should be a percentage of the actual total width of the div.

}
```

Comment: Thanks. Replaced px with % and removed setInterval(). All works.